# UITabBar tab pushes new ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Let's say I have 4 items in my `UITabBar`: A B C D.

Via the delegate methods, D pushes a new `viewController` from the `UITabBar's` `navigationController`, (removing the tabBar for that one view).

This works fine, but how can I keep the `UITabBar` from showing a blank view for D when going back from the new view?

I tried setting the `selectedIndex` to the previous index on push, but that just hangs the app (seems to work fine for modals, just not when pushing.)

Comment: It's hard to understand your question, Can you describe the UI flow and the problem more?

Comment: You may need to wait for a viewWillAppear from D before you use selectedIndex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret this correctly, when you're pushing a view as a result of selecting a tab, you're simultaneously changing the tab that's selected. This is probably trying to then change the view hierarchy that you're currently pushing a view on (that would be the result of selecting the other tab that you're trying to set it to). So it's probably crashing because it's replacing a view that's in the process of being displayed.

Also, from the sound of it you're using a `UITabBarController` inside of a `UINavigationController`. Apple says that you're not supposed to place a `UITabBarController` inside another view controller. The following is taken from Apple's docs on `UITabBarController`:

> When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

If this is the case, you should redesign your app so that you're not containing the tab bar controller in any other view controllers, or your app may behave oddly or stop working at some point.

If you wanted to make things behave exactly how you want them to, you could use a UITabBar directly, and implement your own UITabBarDelegate.